# LWJGL - OpenGL - Camera rotation

Tags: opengl, matrix, camera, rotation, lwjgl

i tried to create a first person camera. I took a piece of code of my XNA project and tried to convert it into java (LWJGL).

```
Matrix4f mx = Matrix4f.rotate(pitch, new Vector3f(1, 0, 0),
            new Matrix4f(), null);

   Matrix4f my = Matrix4f.rotate(yaw, new Vector3f(0, 1, 0),
            new Matrix4f(), null);

    Matrix4f rotationMatrix = Matrix4f.mul(mx, my, null);

    Vector4f tmp = Matrix4f.transform(rotationMatrix, new Vector4f(0, 0,
            -1, 0), null);

    target = new Vector3f(position.x + tmp.x, position.y + tmp.y,
            position.z + tmp.z);

    GLU.gluLookAt(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.position.z,
            this.target.x, this.target.y, this.target.z, 0, 1.0f, 0);
```

Pitch and yaw will increase/decrease if i move the mouse. At the start of running my game it works fine but after some movements i cant look down or up. Should it happen if my position is < 0 ?

The XNA code which works perfekt:

```
         Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(yaw);

        camera.Target = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Forward, rotationMatrix) + camera.Position;
        this.viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(this.position, this.target, Vector3.Up);
```

### EDIT

So I figured out that there is something different between LWJGL and XNA for rotating a matrix.

Java:

```
Matrix4f mx = Matrix4f.rotate(1.2345f, new Vector3f(1,0,0),new Matrix4f(),null);
```

Result:

{1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0} {0.0 0.3299931 -0.9439833 0.0}{0.0 0.9439833 0.3299931 0.0}{0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0}

XNA

```
Matrix.CreateRotationX(1.2345f)
```

Result:

{1,0,0,0} {0,0.3299931,0.9439833,0} {0,-0.9439833,0.3299931,0} {0,0,0,1}

The difference is -0.9439833 and +0.9439833 ... can someone explain me why there are different results? Isnt it the same function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i see. Ok well thats makes the different. Finally i solved my problem. The Problem was the "transform" method in LWJGL. Thats my final working code. Maybe i could optimize it?

```
    public static Matrix4f createRotationX(float pitch) {
    Matrix4f mX = new Matrix4f();
    mX.m00 = 1;
    mX.m10 = 0;
    mX.m20 = 0;
    mX.m30 = 0;
    mX.m01 = 0;
    mX.m11 = (float) Math.cos(pitch);
    mX.m21 = (float) Math.sin(pitch);
    mX.m02 = 0;
    mX.m03 = 0;
    mX.m12 = (float) -Math.sin(pitch);
    mX.m22 = (float) Math.cos(pitch);
    mX.m23 = 0;
    mX.m03 = 0;
    mX.m13 = 0;
    mX.m23 = 0;
    mX.m33 = 1;
    return mX;
}

public static Matrix4f createRotationY(float yaw) {
    Matrix4f mY = new Matrix4f();
    mY.m00 = (float) Math.cos(yaw);
    mY.m10 = 0;
    mY.m20 = (float) -Math.sin(yaw);
    mY.m30 = 0;
    mY.m01 = 0;
    mY.m11 = 1;
    mY.m21 = 0;
    mY.m31 = 0;
    mY.m02 = (float) Math.sin(yaw);
    mY.m12 = 0;
    mY.m22 = (float) Math.cos(yaw);
    mY.m23 = 0;
    mY.m03 = 0;
    mY.m13 = 0;
    mY.m23 = 0;
    mY.m33 = 1;
    return mY;
}

public static Vector3f getNewTarget(Vector3f position,float pitch, float yaw){

    Matrix4f mx = MathUtil.createRotationX(pitch);
    Matrix4f my = MathUtil.createRotationY(yaw);      

    Matrix4f rotationMatrix = Matrix4f.mul(mx, my, null);

    Matrix4f def = new Matrix4f();
    def.m20 = -1;
    def.m00 = 0;
    def.m11 = 0;
    def.m22 = 0;
    def.m33 = 0;

    Matrix4f v4 = Matrix4f.mul(def,rotationMatrix,null);

    return new Vector3f(v4.m00+position.x, v4.m10+position.y, v4.m20+position.z);
}
```